# NSXMLParser can't read last XML node

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I have a little problem. I implemented `NSXMLParser` in my application. When I receive data from web service it's valid XML.
If I receive for example 20 items (nodes) parser parse only 19 of them. It always parse one element less. Why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried NSLogging the foundCharacters function, using `NSLog(@"%@", currentElement);`? Perhaps you'll see what's missing. Also, check if 20 NSLogs are posted in your output.

Comment: Posting some code would be helpful to those who could help you.  We have no idea what the problem could be because we can't see the code.

Comment: I solved it. I did't put in parser to check the top node element. I created new user when parser find 'UserId' element. Now I put user creation in the end of each 'User' node.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion.... have a look at TBXML(http://www.tbxml.co.uk/) This is faster and easier..

Comment: I wouldn't.  It's not a drop in replacement.  Having checked out the source code, I can see it doesn't support name spaces and it doesn't support character sets other than UTF-8.